# Mule - session variables lost after sftp:outbound-endpoint

Tags: mule

Running the following config, I set a session variable before an sftp outbound endpoint and after it its not available anymore. I thought session variables were meant to be available across transport barriers? Am I doing something wrong?

```
<set-session-variable variableName="total" value="#[payload.size()]" />
        <foreach>
            <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
        </foreach>


        <sftp:outbound-endpoint encoding="UTF-8"
            connector-ref="sftp-out" exchange-pattern="request-response" outputPattern="#[flowVars.filename]"
            host="${sftp.host}" port="${sftp.port}" path="${sftp.output.path}" user="${sftp.username}"
            responseTimeout="60000" identityFile="${app.home}/${sftp.keyPath}" passphrase="${sftp.passphrase}" />

<logger level="INFO" message="#[sessionVars.total]" />
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong there, but you are sharing just fractions of your code. Try again with a trivial use case, different settings, more logging, newer Mule version, etc.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Being available through transport barrier means that are still available when sending the message through a VM outbound endpoint, inside the same server (same app or different apps). 
This is useful for sharing behaviour between flows, use transactions, make asynchronous processing or distribute load in a cluster.
Regards.